# Angular: Trying to inject into a service to component

Tags: angular

I am trying to inject a function from the service into a component
It is important to note that **the function works in the component**, but when I try to inject it from the service it does not work (no error, the code does not work)

My service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ElevatorService {
  floor = new ReplaySubject<number>(1);
  floorNumber: number = -1;


  constructor() { }

  up() {
    const floor = this.floor;
    floor.pipe(
        take(1),
        filter((v) => v < 20),
        map((v) => v + 1)
      )
      .subscribe((v) => this.floor.next(v));
      return floor;
  }
```

my component.ts:

```
export class ElevatorComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor(private elevatorService: ElevatorService) { }
    
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  
  up() {
    this.elevatorService.up();
  }
```

my component.html:

```
<input type="button" value="Up" (click)="up()" >
```

Comment: Are you doing something with floor anywhere?

Comment: Sorry I’m confused. So how do you know it’s not working? Where are you subscribing to the floor subject?

Comment: @MikeOne Everything that is here is inside the component:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zbrapb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: Your service doesn’t seem to be in the stackblitz?

Comment: It will make things a lot easier to help you out?

Comment: @MikeOne If I do it in the service it will not work as I tried

Answer (score 1):

Reason is because your `ReplaySubject` does not have initial value. You have to set initial value on init:

```js
export class ElevatorService {
  floor = new ReplaySubject<number>(1);
  floorNumber: number = -1;

  constructor() {
    this.floor.next( ... // initial value);
  }
    
  up() {
    const floor = this.floor;
    floor.pipe(
        take(1),
        filter((v) => v < 20),
        map((v) => v + 1)
      )
      .subscribe((v) => this.floor.next(v));
      return floor;
  }
}
```

And if you don't need ReplaySubject, maybe because of needn't repeated values, - just use `BehaviorSubject` with initial state in constructor:

```js
floor = new BehaviorSubject<number>(1);
```

Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ycrbcp?file=src/app/elevator.service.ts) for you to play with.

Comment: I initialized it here floor = new ReplaySubject <number> (1);
And what you said does not help

Comment: You have not initialized. It's a buffer size.

Comment: this code works, just try it

Comment: You can learn more https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/ReplaySubject

Comment: I tried to initialized like this:

 **ngOnInit() {
    this.floor.next(1);
  }**

Comment: Maybe you needn't ReplaySubject, think about it

Comment: But I could not in any other way implement it

Comment: I tried to switch to BehaviorSubject as well and it does not help

Comment: @NadavPall oops, I forgot service cant have OnInit hook. Just do it in the constructor.

Comment: You working example on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ycrbcp?file=src/app/elevator.service.ts

Comment: Anton is right, you probably want to use a `BehaviorSubject`. A `ReplaySubject` with a buffer size of 1 makes very little sense.